# Two Filters in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am developing a Crystal report and I am bringing the data based on Order No and Mobile No.

I need a data even when Mobile No. does not exist but when I provided two condition together and Mobile No is not available then I am not able to bring the data based on Order no.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two conditions on one table you probably have something like this:

```
{Order Condition} and {Mobile Condition}
```

and need something like this for always with the order and sometimes Mobile:

```
{Order Condition} and ( isnull({Mobile}) or {Mobile Condition})
```

Comment: Thanks Jim for you Quick response. Your first condition didn't worked out because i lost the data based on Order No. I tried with your second condition {PURCHASE_ORDER\.ORDER_NO} = {?Order-No} and isnull({COMM_METHOD\.METHOD_ID} = "Mobile") or {COMM_METHOD\.METHOD_ID} = "Mobile"      but it is giving error "A field is required here"   can you please modify condition and give me exact  O/p @Jim Lutz

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing parentheses for the isnull function. it takes exactly one data field, and not a comparison.

Comment: {PURCHASE_ORDER\.ORDER_NO} = {?Order-No} and (isnull({COMM_METHOD\.METHOD_ID}) or {COMM_METHOD\.METHOD_ID} = "Mobile") when i am trying with this condition it's giving me hundreds of records @Jim Lutz

Comment: This means that you're looking for only records with that order number, and records that have a null Method, or Method of "Mobile". I thought you were going to use a mobile number (This is what I meant as Mobile), not the method.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to have a data with kind of condition.          i would like to  have data based on Order-No and if it has Mobile-No then it has to bring some other records otherwise it has to remain blank.    but when i am trying with null then it gives me hundreds of record. @Jim Lutz

Comment: But you're not comparing with the mobile number in this code, you're using this method field. You may also be missing some parentheses, which would cause this effect, though I don't see it in the code you submitted? I suppose I should mark the fields and conditions with curly braces; I'll do that.

Comment: Correction: I do see in the code here that you didn't have parentheses at first, but later added the parentheses.

Comment: I tried with all the condition with parentheses and without parentheses but it's not changing the result @Jim Lutz

Comment: Using the Method field would require a different way of solving the issue. If you want to use this field, ask a different question.